# Can someone help me with this error on compiling docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So, I've got an angular application and I'm looking to put it in Docker. I'll show you the Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, and nginx.conf codes.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.20.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4300:80"  #
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        # proxy_pass http://backend-server;  # Substituir por um endereço do back-end
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

So when I do the `sudo docker-compose up` the created containers can start normally and generate the link to view the page in the browser, but when I use this link in the browser the application does not run and only appears "Unable to light up this site"

```
    Starting compose-ex_nginx_1    ... done
Starting compose-ex_frontend_1 ... done
Attaching to compose-ex_frontend_1, compose-ex_nginx_1
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx_1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx_1     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx_1     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.2
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14) 
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 28
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
nginx_1     | 2023/08/28 18:48:20 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | > test-docker@0.0.0 start
frontend_1  | > ng serve
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
frontend_1  | ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |  Raw Size
frontend_1  | vendor.js             | vendor        |   2.34 MB |
frontend_1  | polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 333.18 kB |
frontend_1  | styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 230.46 kB |
frontend_1  | main.js               | main          |  48.12 kB |
frontend_1  | runtime.js            | runtime       |   6.52 kB |
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | | Initial Total |   2.94 MB
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | Build at: 2023-08-28T18:48:32.191Z - Hash: 53658a46702913fb - Time: 7231ms
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | ✔ Compiled successfully.
```

So, I used the `sudo docker-compose logs` to see if there was anything wrong and found this error when going to do the ng serve and consequently does not start.

```
frontend_1  | npm ERR! path /app
frontend_1  | npm ERR! command failed
frontend_1  | npm ERR! signal SIGTERM
frontend_1  | npm ERR! command sh -c -- ng serve
frontend_1  | 
frontend_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
frontend_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-08-28T18_48_21_641Z-debug-0.log
```

I know the problem is in /app but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Don't use the dev server in production, serve the build outputs - e.g. https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/blob/main/Dockerfile

Comment: npm start is one server, nginx is another server. Why 2 servers? Both listening to port 80?

Comment: Usually, we run `npm build`, and then copy the `build` folder contents (build result folder contents) to `nginx/html` folder, and then we start only `nginx`

Comment: Did you fixed above issue?